# Meaning of "$r \to s$ is a tautology" in the definition of "implication" and "equivalence"

Tags: logic, terminology, propositional-calculus

What does it mean to say the following:

$$ r \to s\ is\ a\ tautology$$

I make the following truth table:

$$\begin{array}{ l c c r }
  r & s & \lnot r & r \to s \\
  \hline
  T & T & F & T\ \ \ \\
  T & F & F & F\ \ \  \\
  F & T & T & T\ \ \  \\
  F & F & T & T\ \ \  \\
\end{array}$$

If it is filled out correctly, $r \to s$ is not always true, so it is not a tautology.

So, what am I to think when my book says

> r implies s if $r \to s$ is a tautology.

Is this akin to saying $r$ implies $s$ only when $r \to s$ is true?

Similarly, the book defines equivalence as:

> r is equivalent to s if $r \leftrightarrow s$ is a tautology.

Again, is this similar to saying $r$ is equivalent to $s$ only when $r \leftrightarrow s$ is true?

Comment: I don't understand. "$r \leftrightarrow s$ is a tautology" is symmetric, while "$r$ implies $s$" isn't.

Comment: That might be where my confusion is coming from. Although, to be honest, I just started studying logic two days ago and don't know what it means to say a logical proposition is symmetric yet, either. :)  ...What *does* it mean to say a proposition is symmetric?

Comment: Wait, crap. I just noticed an error in my reading of the book. It says "r implies s if $r \to s$ is a tautology." I'm updating the post now.

Comment: That makes much more sense. So this question is wrong just from the beginning, as I expected.

Comment: What does it mean to say a proposition is symmetrical? Any good links for a newbie?

Comment: Symmetrical means "is the same if you swap the arguments". Now, "$r$ implies $s$" is not symmetric because it is not the same as "$s$ implies $r$". On the other hand $r \leftrightarrow s = s \leftrightarrow r$, so that it is syymetric.

Comment: Yes: $\varphi$ *(logically) implies* $\psi$ (in symbols: $\varphi \vDash \psi$) **iff** $\varphi \to \psi$ is a *tautology* (in symbols: $\vDash \varphi \to \psi$). $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are *formulae* and not *propositional letters*: with prop letters $r,s$, a formula like $r \to s$ will never be a tautology.

Comment: Proof (right to left): if $\varphi\ \to \psi$ is a taut, then (according to the truth table for $\to$) the case when $\varphi$ is *true* and $\psi$ *false* is ruled out. This means that, in every row of the truth table where $\varphi$ is *true* also $\psi$ is, and this satisfy the def of (logical) implication.

Comment: @StudentsTea Please do not use MathJaX to emulate markup in the title. Among other reasons, it is semantically wrong (italicised text is not maths).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r$ implies $s$ when it is impossible for $s$ being false while $r$ is true. That is compatible with saying that $r\rightarrow s$ is a tautology because if it is so, then there is no case in which the antecedent is true and the consequent false (which is the only case that makes the arrow false).

E.g.: let $r$ be $(r_1\wedge r_2)$ and let $s$ be $r_2$. We know $r$ implies $s$ because $(r_1\wedge r_2)\rightarrow r_2$ is a tautology (do the truth table).

The same argument works for logical equivalence. Just work the double arrow as in the previous example. One has to see that whenever $r$ is true, $s$ is true too, and viceversa; and whenever $r$ is false, $s$ is false too, and viceversa. But that is just the same as saying $r\leftrightarrow s$ is a tautology.